# Why my code didn't work using font-awesom in angular?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and I am trying to create a simple web page.
Below is my `component.html` and I don't know why the web page cannot load the font icon.

`favorite.component.html`

```
<span
    class="far"
    [class.fa-star]="isFavorite"
    (click)="onClick()"
>
</span>
```

Below is relevant the `component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'favorite',
  templateUrl: './favorite.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favorite.component.css']
})
export class FavoriteComponent implements OnInit {
  isFavorite: boolean;
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onClick(){
    this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
  }
}
```

I changed the above one to the `<span class="fas fa-star"></span>` then it works. but this is not what I wanted. I would like to use the `[class..]` syntax. I downloaded and installed the font-awesome packages but I don't get this reason.

Appreciate it if you could help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your code

```
<span class="fas fa-star"></span>
```

works try the below code

```
<span
class="fas"
[ngClass]="{'fa-star':isFavorite}"
(click)="onClick()"
  >
```

Answer (score 0):

1. first do this install :

   npm i @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome --save

   npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free --save

   npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core --save

   npm i @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons --save
2. then follow this link : ( choose your icon )

- https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Font_Awesome.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index

3. then code :

   `<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>`

[or with style if u like]

```
<i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="margin-left: -1rem;font-size: 1rem; color:black;margin-top: 0.25rem;"></i>
```

[ as doc suggested - i am putting it in **`<i></i>`** tag ]

**One special note : (from `package.json`)**

[image]

our `npm install` did install font awesome 5.14

so the link I provided in step 2 is for specifically font awesome 5.14 icons

[ the icon u are using may not work here for different version for font awesome, so if u want to use font awesome 5.14 like me , follow my link or goto some link that shows you only 5.14 icons (since our npm is installing 5.14 by deafault - current npm latest - or if u need different version specify it in your `npm install`)

Other font awesome icons may not work here for version mismatch ]

NPM link : (if you want to know more about it)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons